# Why are the Spring client library classes suffixed with Template instead of just client?

Tags: spring, naming-conventions

The ones like RestTemplate, JdbcTemplate, RedisTemplate, etc. Is there any significance to this?

Comment: Why would anyone vote to close this or downvote this? Some people... Sigh. What's the point if you can't ask specific curious questions here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they follow the template design pattern.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern